Why is Move-Item yielding an invalid path error when the path exists?
I have a PowerShell script running inside a SQL agent job that pulls new files down from a blob container, and then does different things with them depending on the file extension. The relevant code to my issue is:
$LoadPath = "M:\sys\in\" 

$blobs = gci $LandTempPath | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false }

foreach ($file in $blobs) {
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file.FullName)

    switch -Regex ($extension)
    {
        '^(.dat|.csv)$' {
            $file | Move-Item -Destination $LoadPath -Force
        }
        '^(.gz|.gzip)$' {
            $file | Inflate -DestPath $LoadPath -RemoveSource $true
        }
        '^.txt' {
            if ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file) -eq 'PLCHD_FL')
            {
                $file | Remove-Item -Force
            }
            else {
                $file | Move-Item -Destination $LoadPath -Force
            }
        }
        default {
            $file | Move-Item -Destination $QuarantinePath -Force
        }
    }
}

When I run the job it pulls down the files as expected. The first file was a .gz file, so it correctly unzipped the file into the $LoadPath location. However the next file was a .csv so when it tried to call Move-Item the job failed with the below message:
Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. A job step received an error at line 32 in a PowerShell script.

The corresponding line is '$file | Move-Item -Destination $LoadPath -Force  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job.

The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Invalid Path: 'M:\sys\in\'.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.

Now I know that the value in $LoadPath is correct, because the first file was successfully extracted to the correct path.

I quess there are special characters in the concerned file name. Try: Move-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Destination $QuarantinePath -Force

That is curious, Cam, because with Get-ChildItem output, $file | Move-Item ... is equivalent to Move-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName ...; /cc @iRon.

@mklement0, indeed, it should be equivalent. Therefore I have done some deeper analyzes and it appears to be a bug in Windows PowerShell 5.1 (see my answer below)

From the given error, it appears that the concerned file has a very specific odd name: '.  

where the last two characters are probably non-breaking spaces (U+00A0) knowing Windows would have removed the dot and any successive tailing normal space otherwise.

Such a file indeed causes the Move-Item cmdlet to fail when the file object is provided via the pipeline in older versions of PowerShell:
Move-Item : Unable to find the specified file.
At Test.ps1:28 char:21
+             $file | Move-Item -Destination $QuarantinePath -Force
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (M:\sys\in\'.  :FileInfo) [Move-Item], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

This appears to be a bug in Windows PowerShell 5.1.
PowerShell (Core) 7.4.5 doesn't exhibit this error.
The workaround for (Windows PowerShell 5.1) is using the -LiteralPath parameter to provide the concerned file:
Move-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Destination $QuarantinePath

